# Liferay Build service

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I am using liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2-ce-ga3 and eclipse jee-oxygen for developing liferay. I'm quite new to liferay.Here's my question.

I imported a new event-listing-portlet from github URL:https://github.com/liferay/liferay-docs/tree/6.1.x/devGuide/code/devGuide-sdk/portlets.
It seemed nice but when I ran build service in service.xlm the console log was:

[Console output redirected to file:/home/hamed/liferay/liferay-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.liferay.ide.eclipse.sdk/sdk.log].

and nothing more.

It does not seem to have ran the build service properly. Any idea why it happens?

note:When I used jdk8 as dedault jdk for running build service I encountered an error saying Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM.So I decided to use jdk1.6.0_45 as default jdk.

note2:The mentioned project can be deployed and used properly on tomcat server.

Comment: Liferay 6.1.2 was released December 2013, sooner rather than later you should upgrade. That being said, it was published in the JDK 6 times, but is compatible with JDK7 as far as I remember. It has never been tested on JDK8 (Liferay's Java version compatibility is largely dependent on the supported Appserver's dictate). If the project can be deployed properly, you might just be missing the output of the buildscript? What's your problem when everything works?

Comment: Thanks for answering.
My problem is that when I change something in my project (for example adding a column into my entity) I can't run service builder to see the changes.

Comment: do you use the liferay developer studio ?

Comment: No I use eclipse oxygen IDE and I added liferay plugin to it using liferay-ide-eclipse-updatesite-1.6.0.(This version of update-site was compatible with my liferay version)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are using non compatible version of liferay plugin sdk,you shoul try with an older version.
Don't forget to follow this [guide](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/installing-the-sdk) when configuring your plugin sdk.